# Data Validation stopped working when I merged workbooks

Tags: excel, merge, validation, vba

I used visual basics to merge 8 workbooks together; however, when I did that my data validation stopped working on all except the very first page of the new workbook. Does anyone know why this may have occurred and what I can do to fix it? Is it possible that there is a way to merge workbooks, without using visual basics, that might keep the data validation? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Where is the data validation picking up the list from?